# Laravel Validation rules: required_without + unique

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This is my Validation rule (works fine):

```
public static array $createValidationRules = [
        'email' => ['required_without:telephone', 'nullable', 'email:rfc'],
        'telephone' => ['required_without:email', 'nullable', 'numeric', 'regex:/^\d{5,15}$/'],
    ];
```

->It says, that at least one of the two colums (email and telephone) are required

Now i want to make the email column unique so i tried:

```
public static array $createValidationRules = [
        'email' => ['required_without:telephone', 'nullable', 'email:rfc|unique:customers'],
        'telephone' => ['required_without:email', 'nullable', 'numeric', 'regex:/^\d{5,15}$/'],
    ];
```

But it doesnt work i get this error:

**`Call to a member function isValid() on null`**

At:

**`E:\brahms-apotheke\vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\Validation\MultipleValidationWithAnd.php`**

Line:

```
 $validationResult = $validation->isValid($email, $emailLexer);
```

i have no idea why this combination doesnt work

Comment: to add another rule it should be another array element, not part of a previous rule, btw to follow your array syntax you are using

Comment: try this 
`'email' => ['required_without:telephone', 'nullable', 'email:rfc', 'unique:customers'],`